# How can I tell Swift to wait until my value is downloaded?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Good morning everyone,

Here's my issue, I'd like to create a `UITableView` with JSON I get from my website API.

The problem is that he executes the override functions first of tableview and my JSON data is not downloaded yet, I've tested and it's downloaded when all the cells are printed ( with no value, for testing ).

Here's my function :

```
func loadOrders()
{   
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "myurlthatIhidebutworks").responseJSON() { (request, response, data, error) in
         println(request)
         println(response)
         println(data)
         println(error)
         self.allOrders = JSON(data!)
     }
}
```

I tried to make it happen in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` this way but it doesn't work.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         self.loadOrders()
}
```

I'd appreciate some help, thanks everyone :)

Comment: There is no reason to use dispatch_async to call your loadOrders method. That method is already asynchronous. Simply call `self.loadOrders()` without the dispatch_async wrapper around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning,
At the end of your function loadOrders() reload your tableView:

```
func loadOrders()
{   
     Alamofire.request(.GET, "myurlthatIhidebutworks").responseJSON() { (request, response, data, error) in
     println(request)
     println(response)
     println(data)
     println(error)
     self.allOrders = JSON(data!)

     // Add this for example
     if data != nil
     {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

**reloadData()** method will call all your delegate methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the fatal error nil value found :( Where should I load loadOrders() ? I tried ViewDidLoad() and Viewwillappear but is that right ? already thanks for your answers

Comment: I had an initialization problem too so it's solved thanks to you :) have a nice day ! thanks again

Comment: it wasn't me .. yeap :)

Answer (score 1):

**that should work like this**

```
func loadOrders()
{   
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "myurlthatIhidebutworks").responseJSON() { (request, response, data, error) in
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
              if(error != nil){
                 println(response)
                 println(data)
                 println(request)
                 self.allOrders = JSON(data!)
              }
              else{
                println(error)
              }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the fatal error nil value found :( Where should I load loadOrders() ? I tried ViewDidLoad() and Viewwillappear but is that right ? already thanks for your answers

Comment: loadOrders first of all it should be in ViewDidLoad

Comment: it gives nil because error is nil, i edited my answer if you approve it, the other can see it is working, happy coding